# "Related Questions" box overlaps with the Title section

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When I type in a question title and tab out of that textbox, the Related Questions box appears, but not in the right place.  It seems to be offset several pixels up and to the right, and overlaps with the title textbox.

[image: Screen Capture]

My hunch is that this is some kind of CSS float/clear screwiness.  I'd investigate it myself but at least half of my gray hair is due to trying to fix exactly these kinds of issues on other websites, and I don't think I'd be able to live through that pain again.

It's pretty noticeable, even without the giant arrow.  Fix it please?

Edit: Forgot to mention, this occurs on Firefox 3.6.10.

Comment: Please note which browsers this is happening on.

Comment: Saw it with FF 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put in a fix, should be in the next deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing it as well, in Firefox 3.6/Snow Leopard.  When I use Firebug to remove the -15px margin on the table that has class **ask-title-table** (the element right above it with the Title text and the input box)  the bug is gone (see second screenshot)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a plausible explanation to me.  I wonder why there'd be a negative margin on that particular element to begin with (perhaps a hack for some other browser...)